# What is more expensive to load in a Gallery, a Bitmap or Drawable?

Tags: android, android-widget

What is more expensive to load in a Gallery, a Bitmap or Drawable???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about a Bitmap class, then technically a Bitmap class would be "more expensive" however it's a derived class of a Drawable so it shouldn't be a big concern.  It may be necessary to use a Bitmap due to what you want to do with a Bitmap or JPG.   Then again depending what the drawable is, that may be more expensive, as there are larger objects.

If you're talking about a bitmap image, it would be the same size as a drawable as it would likely have to be made into a drawable.